# How to toggle index view with "where" in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a table with multiple columns. One is boolean. I have this in my controller:

```
def index
  @matchings = Matching.where(match: '1')
end
```

I only want to have lines with the corresponding value of 1 for the "match" column because usually lines with a value of "0" aren't important. However, I'm wondering whether there is a way to toggle the view without having to go into the controller and edit the `def index` every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "toggle the view"? And what do you intend by "edit the `def index` every time"?

Comment: alright sorry not being precisely enough. I would like to add a "toggle" button to my views/matchigs/index.html.erb in my ruby on rails project. And what i want it to do is to filter for 0 or 1 in the `match` column. I know i could do this through the search engine of my table but i prefer a button that toggles the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just would like to toggle it manually, you can just type

```
localhost:3000/controllername/index?match=0
```

or

```
localhost:3000/controllername/index?match=1
```

if you want to add it from your view you can make a form like this

```
<form class="smart-form">
    <fieldset>
        <section class="col col-3">
            <label class="label font-sm">Toggle view</label>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" name= "match">
                    <option value="0">View 1</option>
                    <option value="1">View 2</option>
                </select><i></i>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

and in your controller type the following

```
def index
  @matchings = Matching.where(:match => params[:match])
end
```

I assume that match is something defined at your model.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just use a query string. Whenever you want to load it with

```
match: '1'
```

add

```
?match=1
```

to the request and whenever you want it with

```
match: '0'
```

add

```
?match=0
```

to the request. For example:

```
/some/index/page?match=1
```

or

```
/some/index/page?match=0.
```

Then in the controller use:

```
def index
  @matchings = Matching.where(match: match)
end

private

def match
  params.require(:match) # reads the value of the `match` param in the query string
end
```

For what it's worth, you can write migrations to create boolean columns. (`TINYINT` in most SQL databases.) Using that, your queries can be changed to

```
Matching.where(match: true||false)
```

which makes a bit more sense for this purpose.

Also, I would avoid naming a column `"match"` altogether. [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-match) is a frequently used Ruby method, and it's best to avoid using common method names like that.